# merge two or more xml files, using xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have many XML files, which I need to merge into one:
hotel1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<breakfast_menu>

<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

</breakfast_menu>
</menu>
```

hotel2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<breakfast_menu>

<food>
<name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

</breakfast_menu>
</menu>
```

hotel3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<breakfast_menu>

<food>
<name>French Toast</name>
<price>$4.50</price>
<description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
<calories>600</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
<price>$6.95</price>
<description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
<calories>950</calories>
</food>

</breakfast_menu>
</menu>
```

I need to first add a value to the name element, in order to know from which file it came from, and merge all xml files.

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<breakfast_menu>

<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles-hotel1</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles-hotel1</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles-hotel2</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>French Toast-hotel3</name>
<price>$4.50</price>
<description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
<calories>600</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Homestyle Breakfast-hotel3</name>
<price>$6.95</price>
<description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
<calories>950</calories>
</food>

</breakfast_menu>
</menu>
```

in a given folder, i need to merge all xml files into one. Just merge their contents. No checks, or updates. Also, i need to keep in the name element, the file each came from, for future reference

Here is my trial.
I need someone more experienced help, in order to use latest xslt-3, and for as xml files that exist in a given folder.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="breakfast_menu">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('hotel1.xml')/menu/breakfast_menu/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider to show us the sample code you have to merge the files so that we can show you how to adapt it to insert the file name. In general you have, whether it is XSLT 2 or 3, functions that give you the base URI https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-base-uri or the document URI https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-document-uri so it is rather easy to get a URI and then extracting the file names as the last part is also easy.

Comment: i would prefer a total rewrite, so as to get a best practices approach

Comment: But what exactly are you struggling with, processing various or all files from a folder (that is usually done in XSLT 2/3 with the `collection` function, but the exact use and possibilities are processor dependent) or simply writing a template matching `food/name` and inserting the file name (I have given you hints on that)?

Comment: in a given folder, i need to merge all xml files into one. Just merge their contents. No checks, or updates. Also, i need to keep in the name element, the file each came from, for future reference

Comment: So check the documentation of the `collection` function of the XSLT processor you use to find out whether/how it allows you to process all XML files of a folder as a sequence. Saxon 9.8 has its documentation in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html, not sure what you use. As for the name, well, use the function I pointed you to.

Comment: Saxon 9.8 is what i use, and i would appreciate a clear solution from anyone who has the expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways in XSLT to do this, one would be to try the new `xsl:merge` instruction, but as I run into problem using that with Saxon 9.8 (see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3883 and https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3884) here is a different way, it seems you simply want to copy all the elements from a certain level, in your case the `food` elements from the third level; a generic stylesheet to do that which takes a select expression as a static parameter (I have kept it generic as `*/*/*` but you can of course spell it out for your documents as `menu/breakfast_menu/food`), a URI and a file name pattern for the input files and then is started with the `xsl:initial-template` (command line option `-it` for Saxon's command line) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string" select="'.'"/>

    <xsl:param name="file-pattern" as="xs:string" select="'hotel*.xml'"/>

    <xsl:param name="merge-select-expression" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'*/*/*'"/>

    <xsl:param name="xslt-pattern-to-add-file-name" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="$merge-select-expression || '/name'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:template _match="{$xslt-pattern-to-add-file-name}">
        <xsl:comment>Copied this {node-name()} element from {tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()]}</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:append-docs(uri-collection($input-uri || '?select=' || $file-pattern))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:append-docs" as="document-node()">
        <xsl:param name="doc-uris" as="xs:anyURI+"/>
        <xsl:source-document href="{head($doc-uris)}" streamable="yes">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="construct">
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-doc-uris" as="xs:anyURI*" select="tail($doc-uris)" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:source-document>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:mode name="construct" on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:template _match="{string-join(tokenize($merge-select-expression, '/')[position() lt last()], '/')}" mode="construct">
        <xsl:param name="remaining-doc-uris" as="xs:anyURI*" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$remaining-doc-uris">
                <xsl:source-document href="{.}" streamable="yes">
                    <xsl:apply-templates _select="{$merge-select-expression}"/>
                </xsl:source-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It should work pretty generic by simply adjusting the parameters and perhaps by adjusting the body of the `<xsl:template _match="{$xslt-pattern-to-add-file-name}">` template as there I have chosen to output the file name in a comment instead of throwing it into the element's content.

For your three samples in a subdirectory `hotel-stackoverflow-test` of where the stylesheet `append.xsl` is and the Saxon command line `-it -xsl:.\append.xsl input-uri=hotel-stackoverflow-test file-pattern=hotel*.xml` I get the output

```
<menu>
   <breakfast_menu>
      <food><!--Copied this name element from hotel1.xml-->
         <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
         <price>$5.95</price>
         <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
         <calories>650</calories>
      </food>
      <food><!--Copied this name element from hotel1.xml-->
         <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
         <price>$7.95</price>
         <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
         <calories>900</calories>
      </food>
      <food><!--Copied this name element from hotel2.xml-->
         <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
         <price>$8.95</price>
         <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
         <calories>900</calories>
      </food>
      <food><!--Copied this name element from hotel3.xml-->
         <name>French Toast</name>
         <price>$4.50</price>
         <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
         <calories>600</calories>
      </food>
      <food><!--Copied this name element from hotel3.xml-->
         <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
         <price>$6.95</price>
         <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
         <calories>950</calories>
      </food>
   </breakfast_menu>
</menu>
```

The code should use streaming with Saxon 9.8 EE and normal XSLT processing with Saxon 9.8 HE or PE.

Comment: really excellent solution, my only concern is i do not have Saxon 9.8 EE, so i guess i will have to wait for 9.9 version

Comment: The code posted above works with 9.8 EE as well as with 9.8 HE, it is only that with EE it uses streaming while HE ignores that and uses conventional processing (i.e. builds a tree of each input document and then processes the nodes in that tree). You would need to wait for 9.9 if you wanted to use the approaches using `xsl:merge` in the linked Saxon issues.

Comment: great, thank you very much for this clarification. I saw that the bug you reported was solved.